# Application crashing while video playing on youtube in weview

Tags: android

I developed an application in which i am loading my youtube channel in webview and it is working fine as expected. i am able to play videos in small screen as well as full screen mode.

But the issue is if I am putting the application in background while the video is playing in full screen mode and and bringing it on foreground application crashing. I have seen the crash log but it is not showing anything from my code I am not getting what is the reason behind the crash. It is showing the NullPointerException but where it came is a mystery.

```
Logcat :

08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen.prepareForFullScreen(HTML5VideoFullScreen.java:187)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen.access$600(HTML5VideoFullScreen.java:24)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen$2.surfaceCreated(HTML5VideoFullScreen.java:124)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:609)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:235)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7678)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1335)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-09 14:21:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(10157):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application is not crashing if i am putting application in background while video is playing in small screen only.

Comment: Please give your code. **You should give code always when that is possible** Without it we cannot help you.

Comment: right now i don't have code with me but will post but is it code level issue or something i missed to add in the code because in exception there nothing related to my code. Anyone else has faced the same?